# FFT result in python is different than in matlab with the same matrix

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, fft

I'm trying to convert matlab code into python. It loads .mat files and plot it into python. Handling the struct in python has been quite hard and I'm still trying to get the hang of it.

When trying to FFT in python, even though the numbers in the matrix are the same, it has a yields a very different value.

In python, the format is in numpy.ndarray.

I'm confused on why this is happening. I think it has something to do with my matrix format in python, even though the numbers are all the same.

[Results in python & matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtPXw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're evaluating over the same axes? Remember that Python is zero indexed and Matlab is one indexed, so if you're evaluating both over axis 1, for instance, those are different.

Comment: You're right, when I put axis = 0, it gives the same result. Thank you! I really need to revise on fast fourier after this.